# Sharepoint click event on listview

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-list

So I thought I had this script working till I ran into the issue with Ajax. I have the script so if the user clicks on the item it will automatically change the value on the item. It was looking until I tried to refresh the listview after the change. It looks like Ajax would be the best bet. However the click event I was using has a issue when Ajax is ran. I looked online and it looks like I need to use the .on instead of the .click. I have tried all different ways but I cant get it to work. The code is below,

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".ms-listviewtable > tbody > tr").click(function(){  //only works before ajax runs
    setTimeout( function() {
    //alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current("https://...");
    var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx);
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Ticket');
    this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(items[0].id);
    this.oListItem.set_item('read','yes');
    this.oListItem.update(); 
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
    }, 200);  //had to be put in place to give time for the list to be selected
}); 
});
```

So how can I convert this line to use the .on, 
$(".ms-listviewtable > tbody > tr").click(function(){

or another way to do a click event on the listview. Meaning if they click in item on the list and it run this code.